# Simplificar consulta mysql con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy realizando una consulta a mi base de datos para mostrar el contenido en una tabla de una pagina web php. Quiero mostrar dos tablas, una con ingresos y otra con gastos. Tengo el siguiente código, en el que para hacer esto, he duplicado el código que crea la tabla.

Dejo el código `php`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$link = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname=personal','root','admin');

?>

<table class="table table-hover">
    
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:grey; border-bottom: 3px solid black;">
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
            <th>CONCEPT</th>
            <th>OPERATION</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

<?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from cashflow where operation="IN"') as $row){ ?> 
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['operation_date'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['amount'] ?> €</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['entity'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "INCOME" ?></td>
 </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
</table>

<table class="table table-hover">
    
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:grey; border-bottom: 3px solid black;">
        <th>DATE</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
            <th>CONCEPT</th>
            <th>OPERATION</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

<?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from cashflow where operation="OUT"') as $row){ ?> 
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['operation_date'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['amount'] ?> €</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['entity'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "SPENDING" ?></td>
 </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi pregunta es si esto se puede "simplificar" para hacer el código más sencillo sin duplicar tanto.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Absolutamente, mira el código que es idéntico e imagina las diferencias con variables; Tip: `foreach( ['IN','OUT'] as $op ){`.

Comment: Puedes agrupar por `operation`, incluso creando un objeto más o menos así desde la misma consulta: `{"IN":[{"operation_date":"unaFecha","amount":"999","entity":"abc"},{"operation_date":"unaFecha","amount":"999","entity":"abc"}],"OUT":[{"operation_date":"unaFecha","amount":"999","entity":"abc"},{"operation_date":"unaFecha","amount":"999","entity":"abc"}]}` y luego leerlo como un JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $link = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname=personal','root','admin');
        ?>
        
        <table class="table table-hover">
            
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:grey; border-bottom: 3px solid black;">
                    <th>DATE</th>
                    <th>AMOUNT</th>
                    <th>CONCEPT</th>
                    <th>OPERATION</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from cashflow where operation="IN" AND operation="OUT"') as $row){ ?> 
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['operation_date'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['amount'] ?> €</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['entity'] ?></td>
                    <?php if($row['operation'] == "IN"){ ?>
                        <td><?php echo "INCOME"; ?></td>
                        <?php } else if($row['operation'] == "OUT") { ?>
                        <td><?php echo "SPENDING"; ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
                
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No es correcto en mi caso

Comment: @winset porque no?